Does anyone have any information for IC em78p259nd14j
I am working on a VertaMax power inverter with this IC. The output drive circuit will not power on. Part number em78p259nd14j. I can't find much information as to, is this IC a drop in part? Or does it need firmware to make it function? And what would be it's function in a power inverter.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's an 8-bit Microcontroller made by ELAN Microelectronics Corp. The datasheet for which can be found readily on your favourite search engine (use the series part number EM78P259N in your search).
Yes it requires firmware to function - the controller will be programmed with a custom firmware to perform the desired function of the inverter. Things like controlling the display (based on the connector called "Display"), possibly generating control signals and monitoring the switches used within the inverter bridge.

I have found the part on aliexpress, would the part be able to be installed on the pcb and function as a drop in part? Does the IC have a basic logic program to function as the part that is on the pcb? Thanks for your help

@Pattech24 The part requires programming. You won't be able to simply drop in a new one without having the correct firmware programmed into it. This will be proprietary and unlikely to be freely available anywhere

That is what I was afraid of. Thanks for the help,Pat

when I check the part number, the 14 pin dip package is not shown. Does this IC have a different program or pin configuration than the 18 or 20 pin model?
